# passing the url value to servlet from javascript using ajax and getting error "Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined"

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

NewServlet.java: this is my servlet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        String url = request.getParameter("url");
        System.out.println("my url"+url);
   }

this is my javascript file in which i am getting the url from document.URL and want to pass it on servlet NewServlet.java
//demo.js: this is my javascript

var url=document.URL;
alert(url);
$.ajax({
        url:"NewServlet.java",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:'url',
        data: {url:url}
        });
```

this is my code and i am getting the error

```
"Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined".
```

I want to pass the current webpage URL from my JavaScript value to my servlet.

and if I am using below process :-

```
var url=document.URL;
alert(url);
var url1="TMServlet?val1="+url;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    request=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject)
{
    request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
try
{ 
   request.open("GET",url1,true);
   request.send();
}
catch(e)
{
    alert("unable to connect server");
}
```

Then I am getting the below error :-

```
1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Http://www.mca.gov.in/TMServlet?val1=http://www.mca.gov.in/ 

2. Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.                                    
jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
```

In error 1 i just want val1's value but why it is appending `http://www.mca.gov.in/TMServlet?val1=`  this?

And in second error I want to know where I need to add  jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3 file.

Please help if any one know the answer as soon as possible.